# JUnit test is still passing even though sql query should return no records

Tags: java, sql, junit, cucumber, junit4

I am writing cucumber tests that query an SQL Server database.

The below query should fail, as the record does not exist in the table. But, the test passes.

```
try { 
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER); 
        System.out.println("Connecting to database..."); 
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);  

        System.out.println("Connected database successfully..."); 
        stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
        String sql = "SELECT id FROM tclientlink WHERE id = '0000060115123'"; 
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()) { 
            int id  = rs.getInt("goald_client_id"); 
            System.out.print("ID IS HERE: " + id); 
            assertEquals(60115, id);
        } 
        rs.close(); 
    } catch(SQLException se) { 
        se.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } finally { 
        try { 
            if(stmt!=null) stmt.close();  
        } catch(SQLException se2) { 
        }
        try { 
            if(conn!=null) conn.close(); 
        } catch(SQLException se) { 
            se.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Goodbye!"); 
}
```

Comment: What is the result of your query?

Comment: @YitianZhang Hi, I have added the code that should be failing above. So this method should fail above. You can see the sys.out's that I have added, but the below details are the only details being logged to the console:  **Connecting to database...
Connected database successfully...
Goodbye!**

Comment: If the record doesn't exist in the table then the resultset will be empty, which means that `assertEquals(60115, id);` is never executed.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Hi, ok, thanks for that. what changes do I need to make to the code so it fails if the resultset is empty?

Comment: If it should fail if nothing is found then you can replace your `while (rs.next()) { ... }` loop with a simple check: `if (!rs.next()) { fail("No data found"); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop is not executing because there is no records in resultset and by default test case is passed,
please do following changes

```
while(rs.next()) { 
    int id  = rs.getInt("goald_client_id"); 
    System.out.print("ID IS HERE: " + id); 
    assertEquals(60115, id);
}
```

Change above code with

```
int noOfRecords = 0;

while(rs.next()) { 
    int id  = rs.getInt("goald_client_id"); 
    System.out.print("ID IS HERE: " + id); 
    assertEquals(60115, id);
    noOfRecords ++;
} 

if( noOfRecords == 0 ) {
    assertEquals(true, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have `NullPointerException` on the following line :

```
int id  = rs.getInt("goald_client_id");
```

and it goes to the exception block, just add the following statement in all exception blocks

```
assertEquals(true, false);
```

Comment: I have added this into all catch statements, but the test is still passing